# Async a group of functions to over an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I have an array of four JSON objects, and I want to add three new fields to each of these objects. To do this, I have one async function for each new field to add. Ideally, what I want to do is limit the async function to only 2 updates each. Then at the end, callback the original function and print out the newly formed array. But I can't get this to work, although I feel like I'm close...

```
var async = require('async');

// My Array of JSON objects
var allIssues = [
    { id: '1', color: 'blue' },
    { id: '2', color: 'red' },
    { id: '3', color: 'gold' }
];

addExtraFeaturesToEachissue(allIssues, function(data) { console.log(data); });

function addExtraFeaturesToEachissue(allIssues, callback) {
    async.each(
        allIssues,
        async.applyEach([addheight, addWidth, addWeight]),
        callback(data)
    );
}

function addHeight(issue, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        issue.fields['height'] = "1000";
        callback(issue);
    }, 100);
} 
function addWidth(issue, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        issue['width'] = "100";
        callback(issue);
    }, 300);    
}
function addWeight(issue, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        issue.['weight'] = "500";
        callback(issue);
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Please include the shape of the expected JSON array. Also, why are you opting for the async approach and delaying the filling of your JSON array using timeouts ?

Comment: [
    { id: '1', color: 'blue', 'width' : 100, 'weight' : '500', height : '1000' },
    { id: '2', color: 'red' ,'width' : 100, 'weight' : '500', height : '1000 },
    { id: '3', color: 'gold', 'width' : 100, 'weight' : '500', height : '1000 }
];

and they area actually more complicated functions, I'm just putting in a random timer to show that they do take a while to perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing that the called functions will do some long task, honestly I don't see the need of using async, why don't just use Promise?

```
// My Array of JSON objects
var allIssues = [
    { id: '1', color: 'blue' },
    { id: '2', color: 'red' },
    { id: '3', color: 'gold' }
];

addExtraFeaturesToEachissue(allIssues, function(data) { console.log(data); });

function addExtraFeaturesToEachissue(allIssues, callback) {
  var requests = allIssues.map((issue) => {
    return addHeight(issue).then(addWidth).then(addWeight);
  });
  Promise.all(requests).then((data) => console.log('done', data));
}

function addHeight(issue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      issue.height = "1000";
      resolve(issue);
    }, 100);
});
}
function addWidth(issue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        issue.width = "100";
        resolve(issue);
    }, 300);
  });
}
function addWeight(issue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        issue.weight = "500";
        resolve(issue);
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

**Edit** I've just seen that you whant the complete array at the end. As suggested by Jared Smith, you can use Promise.all ;)